# What's the difference between Unit and Nothing?

Tags: scala

Both types `Unit` and `Nothing` indicate a function that does not return anything. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`Unit` is a type that has exactly one value ‒ see [Unit type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type). On the other hand, `Nothing` has *no possible* value - see [Bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type).

A function that doesn't return anything must have the return type `Unit`. If it were `Nothing` then the function could not return a result. The only way to exit the function would be by an exception.

---

`Nothing` is used in a different way. It is characterized by two properties:

1. `Nothing` is a subtype of every other type (including `Null`).
2. There exist no instances of this type.

When is this useful? Consider `None`:

```
object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

Because `Option` is covariant in its type parameter and `Nothing` is a subtype of everything, `Option[Nothing]` is a subtype of `Option[A]` for every type `A`. So, we can make one object `None` which is a subtype of `Option[A]` for every `A`. This is reasonable, since `Nothing` cannot be instantiated so `Option[Nothing]` will always be without a value. Similarly

```
object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

---

`Unit` corresponds to logical true and `Nothing` corresponds to logical false under the [Curry-Howard isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry-Howard_Isomorphism), where we view types as propositions and functions as proofs, .

Answer (score 25):

`Unit` means that (a) function has side effects like input and output, (b) these side effects are the main goal of the function. Of course, a function can have side effects even if its type is different from `Unit`.

`Nothing` is a special type in Scala, because (a) it has no values (Unit has exactly one value - `()`), so you cannot return a value of type `Nothing`, and (b) it is a subtype of every other type. That means that if something has the type `Nothing`, it can be used instead of any other type (via subtyping), but it won't produce any result. This is useful for dealing with exceptions - the `throw` expression has a type of `Nothing`, so it can be used everywhere in a program.

Simply, `Nothing` means that there was an error or termination of a program and nothing was returned, while `Unit` means there were side effects, but execution ended normally with no result.

[Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed) has a nice explanation of that.

Answer (score 7):

To add one aspect to Petr's reply: `Nothing` plays an important role in the type hierarchy. It is a bottom type. That means that it is a subtype of every other type, which is like the opposite of `Any`, which is a supertype of everything. You can find a nice explanation [here](http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/learning-scala-type-hierarchy-and-object-equality).

Comment: @downvoters: When I wrote this answer, Petr's reply did not mention the bottom type aspect at all. He only added it later.

Answer (score 3):

**Unit**

Unit is same as **void** of Java. void in java is a keyword but Unit is an Object in Kotlin.

Now if a function returns Unit in Kotlin, it means that it doesn't return anything meaningful, that function just executes a bunch of code and gives back the **execution flow**.

**Nothing**

Nothing is a different kind altogether. You can't relate it with anything in Java. **There is nothing as such as Nothing in java.**

Nothing means the **end of execution**. If a function returns Nothing, means literally nothing it returns. Not even the **execution flow**.

Nothing is like a black hole, anything that goes in doesn't come out, Not even the light (light is "execution flow" here). In the case of Unit, least light comes out.

So, if a function returns Nothing, the flow of code ends there and anything written after that is **Unreachable**.

Now see the code below,

```
fun main() {
    unitFun()
    println("after unit")
    nothingFun()
    println("after nothing")   //you get warning here saying "unreachable code"
}

fun nothingFun(): Nothing {
    println("inside nothing")
    throw Exception()
}

fun unitFun(): Unit {
    println("inside unit")
}
```

Output will be

```
inside unit
after unit
inside nothing
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception
```

**NOTE:** you get warning as soon as you write

```
println("after nothing")     UnReachable Code
```

And you know the reason, it's because nothingFun doesn't even send back the execution flow.

One more thing to complete this here is, any function that returns Nothing has to throw an exception of any kind.

**REASON:** If you write some general statement (and not throw an exception) then the function will match the return type and we don't have anything that returns Nothing, means we don't have anything that sucks the execution flow and never returns it back. Everything returns something, even Unit is something.

Now, one can say that Nothing is a class so we can make object of it and return that itself. Nohhhhhhh? A big nohhhh?

Nothing class has one constructor but it is private, so you can't even make an object of it.

**Last Bit**

Behind the scene, Unit is converted into void(small v) in the decompiled byte code while Nothing is converted into Void(capital V).

see the below code,

```
var user = null               //First
var user : User? =null        //Second
```

Here, the Second statement shows, **user** of Nullable-User type.
What is the type of **user** of the first statement?

any guess?

It's **Nullable-Nothing** type.

try to see the first statement as

```
var user : Nothing? = null
```

Now what's happening under the hood,

```
Void user = (Void)null;              //First
User user = (User)null;        //Second
```