# Why I get a () when I running my Scala code?

Tags: scala

```
object test {
  def multBylarge(input: Array[Int]): Int = {
    var result=0
    var lst: List[Int]=List()
    if(input.length == 0) result+=1
    else
      for(elements <- input) {
        lst = lst :+ elements
      }
    var newlst = lst.sortWith(_ > _)
    result += newlst(0) * newlst(1)
    result
  }

  def check2(input: Array[_]) = input.foreach {
    case _:Int => multBylarge(_)
    case _:Double => "this is a double array"
    case _:Float => "this is a float array"
    case _=> "this is not a value"
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      println(check2(Array(1,3,5,1,3,4)))
  }
}
```

this is my code, I just have no idea. It will be appreciated if anyone can help me with it. And I am not familiar with scala code, so if there has any other problem, please let me know.

Comment: There is a little mistake at Line 5, it's not "result += 1", it's just "result"

Comment: The whole code is completely unidiomatic and is filled of bad practices, if you are doing this for learning my advice would be to pick a proper book, course or tutorial about the language.

Answer (score 3):

[Scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Array.html) is your friend. `foreach` has return type of [`scala.Unit`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.5/scala/Unit.html) (see [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539822/whats-the-difference-between-unit-and-nothing)) which has only one value - `()`:

> `def foreach[U](f: (T) => U): Unit`
>
> Apply `f` to each element for its side effects.

So actual signature of your method is `def check2(input: Array[_]): Unit`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Update check2 match on input rather then foreach (since `multBylarge` requires a array input anyway, foreach wouldn't work here since it iterates over every item in the array then tries to apply it to `multBylarge`)
2. Wrap result in a Either (You can think if it as Left = Failure and Right = Successful result)
3. Then match on the result in the main function to pretty print the result/error

```
object test {
  def multBylarge(input: Array[Int]): Int = {
    var result=0
    var lst: List[Int]=List()
    if(input.length == 0) result+=1
    else
      for(elements <- input) {
        lst = lst :+ elements
      }
    var newlst = lst.sortWith(_ > _)
    result += newlst(0) * newlst(1)
    result
  }

  def check2(input: Array[_]): Either[String, Int] = input match {
      case ints: Array[Int] => Right(multBylarge(ints))
      case _: Array[Double] => Left("this is a double array")
      case _: Array[Float]  => Left("this is a float array")
      case _.               => Left("this is not a value")
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      check2(Array(1,3,5,1,3,4)) match {
       case Right(result) => println(s"Result is $result")
       case Left(error)   => println(s"Failed with $error")
    }
  }
}
```